# AddMessage in batch process for a queue

Tags: azure, queue, azure-storage-account

I want to include a lot of records in a queue of Azure.

I don't want to do it one to one. I would like to create a batch process to know if something went wrong.

Because I need to do a rollback proccess if something went wrong.
For example to run a batch of 50 and if the queue gets the 50 records receive a success.

if something went wrong receive a that information.

I know I can include records in a table in a batch way with this command:

```
            cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);
```

And I saw on internet a way to do it batch process for queues. 
But I think this post it is related with performance, more than batch process success or not.

Any idea? any magic library?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It’s not possible to send messages in a batch to a storage queue.

Azure Service Bus on the other hand supports this functionality. You might want to look into it if batching is important for you.

Comment: What is the improvement with this approach?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Can you please elaborate?